# forEach method seems to skip an entry

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

### Aim

I am trying to make a function which would take an array of "votes" and return an object containing the number of times each "candidate" received a score of 1.

For example an array such as:

```
[
    {
        "blue": 1,
        "red": 3,
        "purple": 2,
        "yellow": 4
    },
    {
        "blue": 2,
        "red": 3,
        "purple": 4,
        "yellow": 1
    },
    {
        "blue": 1,
        "red": 2,
        "purple": 4,
        "yellow": 3
    },
    {
        "blue": 3,
        "red": 4,
        "purple": 2,
        "yellow": 1
    }
];
```

should return an object

```
{
    "blue": 2,
    "red": 0,
    "purple": 0,
    "yellow": 2
}
```

---

### Current Code

Currently I have written the function

```
// adds up the first choice results from raw data
// return object containing number of first choice votes each candidate received
const add_first_choices = function (raw_data) {
    // create object to store number of first choices
    const storage_obj = empty_candidate_obj(raw_data);

    // loop through results, adding first choices to storage_obj
    raw_data.forEach(function (single_voter_obj) {
        Object.values(single_voter_obj).forEach(function (value) {
            if (value === 1) {
                storage_obj[getKeyByValue(single_voter_obj, value)] += 1;
            }
        });
    });
    return storage_obj;
};
```

which uses the following two other functions

```
// returns object of candidate names, each with value of 0
const empty_candidate_obj = function (raw_data) {
    const input_data = raw_data;
    let first_vote = input_data[0];
    const keys = Object.keys(first_vote);
    keys.forEach(function (key) {
        first_vote[key] = 0;
    });
    return first_vote;
};
```

and

```
// returns key from object value
const getKeyByValue = function (object, value) {
    return Object.keys(object).find((key) => object[key] === value);
};
```

---

### Problem

When inputting the above array into my function it returns

```
{
    blue: 1,
    red: 0,
    purple: 0,
    yellow: 2
}
```

=> Not as expected!

Do you know what I have done wrong?

Thanks for any replies :)

Comment: `const output = {}; for (const o of raw_data) { for (const key in o) { output[key] ||= 0; if (o[key] === 1) output[key]++ } }`

Comment: In cases like this, debugging skills come in very handy. Check out [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for some tips go get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with this line:

```
const input_data = raw_data;
```

Copying an array of objects is problematic because copying the array doesn't automatically make new copies of the objects. It's just a new array with references to the original objects, so if you change an object in the new array you're changing the original object.

So you need to make [new copies of the objects](https://jsfiddle.net/6rdj1h3u/) too:

```
const input_data = raw_data.map(obj => ({...obj}));
```

You can solve your problem slightly simpler with [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const data = [{"blue":1,"red":3,"purple":2,"yellow":4},{"blue":2,"red":3,"purple":4,"yellow":1},{"blue":1,"red":2,"purple":4,"yellow":3},{"blue":3,"red":4,"purple":2,"yellow":1}];

// We initialise the `reduce` with a new `{}` object,
// which is updated with each iteration.
// `acc` is the accumulator, `c` is the current element
const result = data.reduce((acc, c) => {

  // For each object in the array we grab the key and value
  Object.entries(c).forEach(([ key, value ]) => {

    // If our initial object doesn't already have a key
    // that matches, create one and set it to zero
    acc[key] = acc[key] || 0;

    // And if the value is one, increase the value of that property
    if (value === 1) acc[key]++;
  });

  // Make sure to return the initial object
  // for the next iteration
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

With respect to your code the problem is in this line of empty_candidate_obj funcation

```
  let first_vote = input_data[0];
```

Update you code to send a copy

`let first_vote = {...input_data[0]}`;

Object works on reference. so it's like your first object of your dataset values are updated to 0 as well with your empty object

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a reducer something like this:

```js
const results = [
    {
        "blue": 1,
        "red": 3,
        "purple": 2,
        "yellow": 4
    },
    {
        "blue": 2,
        "red": 3,
        "purple": 4,
        "yellow": 1
    },
    {
        "blue": 1,
        "red": 2,
        "purple": 4,
        "yellow": 3
    },
    {
        "blue": 3,
        "red": 4,
        "purple": 2,
        "yellow": 1
    }
];

const empty_obj = {
    "blue": 0,
    "red": 0,
    "purple": 0,
    "yellow": 0
}
result = results.reduce( reducer , empty_obj)
console.log( result )

function reducer( acc, val ) {
  for( key in val )
    if( val[key] === 1 ) acc[key]++;

  return acc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this function:**

```js
function candidateScore1Times(array) {
  const newObj = {}

  for (const score of array) {
    Object.keys(score).forEach(elem => {
      if (newObj[elem] != null)  {
        if (score[elem] == 1) {
          newObj[elem]++
        }
      } else {
        score[elem] == 1 ? newObj[elem] = 1 : newObj[elem] = 0
      }
    })
  }
  return newObj
}
```